# Scroll automatically to Radio Group inside Scroll view

Tags: android, scrollview

I have many Radio Group added dynamically inside Scrollview, each one include some radio button, and when scroll down at bottom of view, I have a button called Submit, Click on this button and I want scrollview scroll automatically to the first group radio that there is not any its radio button was checked.

This problem is similar with when click an element on HTML and scroll to other element On page of web development.

Comment: ">Click it and check if have any radio group that its radio button don't check yet, then have to scroll to the first one"   

I don't quite follow, can you edit your question to make it clearer?

Comment: I updated my question. Do you understand my meaning ? :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
final ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.your_scrollview);
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.your_radiogroup);
            scrollView.scrollTo(0, radioGroup.getBottom());
        }
});
```

Comment: this mean I have to add id attribute for radio group when it was created ? 
Because radio group was created dynamically

Comment: No, you can just store the reference to it, and use that one.

Comment: right now how can get id of radio group ? 
<br> because radio group was created programmatically, so can not find using R.id.your_radiogroup as you said

Comment: Save the reference to it in a class variable